# PHP file_get_contents returns 404

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a very strange Problem. I am trying since 3 hours to the the output from $ht. When i echo $ht the result is http://www.google.com. There is no problem. But when i do file_get_contents with the variable $ht there is no output. I tried already with curl also no ouput - 404....

```
foreach ($hashtweet[1] as $ht)
        {

$html = file_get_contents($ht); //NOT WORKING
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com"); // WORKING
echo $html;

//echo $ht;  = CORRECT OUT OF $ht = http://www.google.com

        }
```

Comment: Can't help you without seeing `$hashTweet`.

Comment: There must be some extra character in the value of `$ht`. You should do `var_dump($ht);` to find out exactly what.

Comment: try printing $ht as - echo("\"$ht\"");

Comment: Hey,

Output of var_dump($ht);

string(21) "http://www.google.com" 

and 

$html = file_get_contents(trim($ht)); 

is also not working....

Comment: Can you put the exact output in your question via edit? Because `google.com` is not 21 chars long.

Comment: http:// www.google.com without the space between / and w extact 21 chars

Answer (score 1):

You should use trim function:

```
$html = file_get_contents(trim($ht));
```

Probably some spaces or other white characters are at the beginning or at the end of string

**EDIT**

In your question you told us the `$ht` is `http://www.google.com` but in comment you told is it's `google.com`. If you want to get `http://google.com` you need to add `http://`. Otherwise it means that you need in current directory file with name `google.com`

**EDIT2**

So you should compare those 2 strings. Add inside your loop:

```
if (trim($ht) == 'http://www.google.com') {
  echo "same strings<br />";
}
else {
  echo "there is difference<br />";
}
```

to make sure those strings are or aren't the same. You told that your $ht return `string(21) "http://www.gooogle.com"` so it's impossible it doesn't work because string `http://www.gooogle.com` string is exactly 21 characters long. Don't you change `$ht` variable before running file_get_contents or after it inside the loop?

Comment: Hey,

Output of var_dump($ht);

string(21) "http://www.google.com" 

and 

$html = file_get_contents(trim($ht)); 

is also not working....

Comment: is beginns with http:// but stackoverflow shortet it to google.com ....http:// www.google.com ...21 charaters

Comment: IT IS http:// www.google.com (WITHOUT THE SPACE) STACKOVERFLOW is shorten links to google.com

Comment: @CubeBoy69 Look at edited answer. However it's impossible that those 2 strings are different because `http://www.google.com` is also 21 characters.

Comment: OMG - CAN'T you read?! I SAID WITHOUT THE SPACE i CANT WRITE http:// www.google.com because stackoverflow is shorten itself to google.com